# Tag Synonym Suggestions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've been doing some tag clean-up (sorry for all the bumps) and came across a few that, in my opinion, should be synonyms. I don't have the privilege to make these changes, but perhaps someone who does, and thinks they should be synonyms, can. For many of these tags, there are few users who can suggest/vote on them so moderator intervention may be required.

**Proposed:**

- [experimental-design](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental-design) ← [experiment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experiment), [experimental](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experimental) - These tags seem redundant.
- [materials](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) ← [lab-reagents](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lab-reagents) - I recently create the [materials](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) tag as a complement to the [methods](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methods) tag and to cover questions that aren't about reagents. I think having the more derived tag [lab-reagents](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lab-reagents) is unnecessary given the large overlap and infrequent use.
- [methods](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methods) ← [lab-techniques](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lab-techniques) - For the same reason as the [lab-reagents](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lab-reagents) tag.

**Completed:**

- [lymphatic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymphatic) ← [lymph](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymph) - I don't particularly like either of these tags. Perhaps we can make a new tag called [lymphatic-system](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymphatic-system) or [lymphology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymphology) (analgous to the current [cardiology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardiology) and [oncology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oncology) tags) and make both of the existing tags synonyms?
- [oncology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oncology) ← [cancer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cancer), [tumor](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tumor), [tumour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tumour) - These tags all seem redundant.
- [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification) ← [identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) - I haven't seen the latter tag used in any question not requesting species identification, nor can I think of a use case outside of species identification.
- [biochemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry) ← [chemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) - These two are often used in conjunction. I also cannot think of a question that would be on-topic here which would require the [chemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) tag but not the [biochemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry) tag.
- [literature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) ← [reference-request](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) - Related to [this topic](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3570/cleaning-up-the-literature-tags). [reference-request](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) seems unnecessary since, to me, using the [literature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) tag in an implicit request for a reference. The [literature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) tag wiki can be edited to specify that it can be used for to request references.

Comment: @Mesentery tumour is already a synonym of cancer, though tumor isn't. I would be in favour of all of these tags being synonyms of oncology. I'll add them to the list.

Comment: I really appreciate the tag efforts and especially the first two points make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

- Merged [oncology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oncology) and [tumor](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tumor) with [cancer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cancer) and also created [oncology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oncology) as a synonym of [cancer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cancer). I chose to keep [cancer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cancer) as the primary tag because it is more common and better understood than oncology.
- Created a [lymphatic-system](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymphatic-system) and merged [lymph](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymph) and
  [lymphatic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymphatic) with it. Also, synonymised [lymph](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymph) with
  [lymphatic-system](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lymphatic-system).
- Merged and synonymized [identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) with [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification). All the questions under [identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) but without [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification) were basically species identification questions. One question was different and was about terminology, so tagged appropriately. Since 84 questions were tagged with [identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) it seemed apt to make it a synonym of [species-identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification) so that in future, the former does not accumulate.
- Merged [chemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) with [biochemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry). I agree that [chemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) has no meaning in this site if it is not [biochemistry](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biochemistry).
- Merged and synonymized [reference-request](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) with [literature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature). [book-recommendation](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation) is still separate. We should have a consensus on whether it should be merged with [literature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature).

---

I am not sure about other suggestions. Your suggestions are logical but the existing tag names seem to be more popular. If others agree for the change then we can rename those tags. At present it seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I'll leave the other ones up there in case people want to discuss them, but they don't seem like crucial changes.